# Youtube Subscribe Button Position

Tags: html, css, button, youtube, subscribe

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find the code. Hopefully one of you can help!

I have a YouTube-subscribe button on my site and it's has a trouble.  In microsoft edge, IE and all browsers it looks like the first link below but only in Chrome I see button correctly. (the second link below)

Here's a code of my button:

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="NAME" data-channelid="ID" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBZCT.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfQMy.png

p.s sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can we have an example?

Comment: Sure. Site: https://mayer.000webhostapp.com/